# How do I get the InstanceTypes associated with an AMI Type?

Tags: go, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I'm producing some code to be used in our product to spin up EKS clusters.

However, I need to query the instance types available in each region which is passed to the CreateNodeGroup call.

One of the calls to CreateNodeGroup requires an AMI type.  And in experimenting with the Amazon UI, the instance types change depending on what AMI type is selected which makes sense.  But, I cannot figure out how to work out what Instance types are applicable to these AMI types:

> AL2_x86_64, AL2_x86_64_GPU, AL2_ARM_64, BOTTLEROCKET_x86_64, BOTTLEROCKET_ARM_64

I got as far as describing the Instance types for a region, but cannot work out how to filter that by AMI type

Any hints or help, greatly appreciated.

```
// Get a list of instance types available in the region
sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    Region:      aws.String("us-west1"),
    Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials(accessKey, secretAccessKey, ""),
})
if err != nil {
    return err
}

svc := ec2.New(sess)
params := &ec2.DescribeInstanceTypesInput{}

types, err := svc.DescribeInstanceTypes(params)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Comment: This is not possible - read the accepted answer here for a complete overview: [List all possible instance types for a specific AMI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270057/list-all-possible-instance-types-for-a-specific-ami)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary - In that case I need to run DescribeInstanceTypes with filters for ARM and X86.